# How do I run Azure WebJobs with pm2

Tags: node.js, azure, pm2

I decided to host my discord bot on Azure with the WebJobs feature in the App Service resource.
I wanted to know how I can run the webJob with pm2 and not the default runtime in Azure

Extra: Is there a way to use the express module on the App Service resource and add some content to the website IF i dont host the bot in WebJobs format

Comment: AFAIK, Currently, there is no option to use **pm2** in Azure web Jobs. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-windows) for express module in app service

Comment: any update regarding the thread?

Comment: I've done it, thanks

Comment: Could you post your steps of how you did? so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using https://github.com/breejs/bree for asynchronous background jobs. I'm using it, give it a chance. Behind the scenes, it uses worker threads, so the main thread of node never gets blocked.

Comment: sure thing, I'll try it out